How to get if there are values to update in CriteriaUpdate in Spring boot?
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaUpdate<TestClass> update = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(TestClass.class);

Root<TestClass> testClass = update.from(TestClass.class);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(update);

Here, I am getting No assignments specified as part of UPDATE criteria on the last line because there are no values to update.
Anyone please guide me how to check if there are any values to update or not.
I tried to get values from CriteriaUpdate object itself with reflection also but not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Provided more explanation.
